# Wordpress Post order

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to re-arrange my recent post in wordpress so they go Ascending/Descending.

Here is my code:

```
    <ul>
<?php query_posts('cat=3,4,5&posts_per_page=5&order=ASC'); foreach ($post as $post)  ?>
<li>
<span class="date"><?php the_time('M j') ?></span>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Each post is pulled from different categories. View site [here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/home/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the standard [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)?

```
<?php

//The Query
query_posts('cat=3,4,5&posts_per_page=5&order=ASC');

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ..
endwhile; else:
 ..
endif;


?>
```

This code should work, if there's another reason that you're using get_posts over query_posts your problem is likely to be your argument list - from what I can see you will need to change

```
get_posts('cat=3,4,5,numberposts=5&order=DESC&orderby=date')
```

to

```
get_posts('cat=3,4,5&numberposts=5&order=DESC&orderby=date')
```

as `&`'s are used to separate parameters.

Comment: updated my post.. no luck not working.. I am not really good in PHP nor Wordpress. So i don't know if my syntax are correct.

Comment: @banjer I included the demo in my post.

Comment: You need to add `orderby=date` to the query_posts parameter

Answer (score 1):

try using "orderby" as well ...

see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

I would put categories 3,4,5 under a parent category.  Then you could just pull in the single category (the parent category).  For example, if you're new parent category is 17, you would do:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=17&numberposts=5&order=DESC&orderby=date'); foreach ($post as $post)  ?>
```

This will display posts in category 17 and any of category 17's children.  Then sorting should happen as you'd expect it to.

Comment: yes but then if I do that my "Blog Categories" would also display the Parent Category instead of just the the categories inside of it.